# How to upload form data with image file to django model using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x

I want to upload image file with some other data to Django database using ajax. Every time I do this using formData it always return empty when debugging. Also my serializer is not validating. Please help me to resolve this problem. Is there any other way to send image file to server.

```js
function add_bike_model(btn){
    debugger;
    var data=new FormData()
    data.append('image',$("#bike_model_name")[0].files[0])
//    BikeModels = document.getElementById('bike_model_name').value;
//    var e = document.getElementById("city_drop");
//    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
//    image = document.getElementById('img_file').value;
//    e.preventDefault();
//    var data = new FormData($('#form').closest('form')[0]);
    console.log('hello')
    data = {"CityForCars":strUser, "BikeModels": BikeModels, 'Image':image}
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                url: baseUrl + "/bike_model/",
                data:new FormData($("#moment-pane-upload-form")[0]),
                success: function(data) {
                  console.log('sucessfully done')
                  console.log(data)
                  window.location.href = baseUrl + "/bike_model/";
                }

            });
}
```

```html
<form name="add_model_form" id="add_model_form"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="comon-form"  method="post">
          <h3>ADD BIKE MODELS</h3>
<div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="avatar-upload">
                <div class="avatar-preview">
                  <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url(/static/Chatbot_Dashboard/img/logo/logo.png);"></div>
                    <img id="bike_image" src="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group-inner">
                <label>Bike Model Name <em>*</em></label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="" type="name" id="bike_model_name" required="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group-inner">
                <label>City <em>*</em></label>
                <select style="width: 100%; background: #fff; padding: 7px;" id="city_drop">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select City</option>
                        {% for city in city.car_city %}
                      <option value="{{city.id}}">{{city.CityForCars}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group-inner">
                <label>Bike Image <em>*</em></label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="" type="file" id="img_file" required="">

              </div>
            </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 <div class="mt20 text-center">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add_bike_model(this);" style="margin-right:10px;">Add</button><a href="/bike_model/"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel"></a>
 </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </form>
```

my python code is -

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    import pdb;
    pdb.set_trace()
    print('a')
    # input_data = json.loads(request.read().decode('utf-8'))
    # print(input_data)
    serializer = serializers.BikeModelSerializer(request.FILES, request.POST)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return render(request, "bike_model_add.html", {'car_city': car_city}, status=200)
return HttpResponse('error', status=400)
```